# Endogeneity in Stata

Tags: panel-data, stata

I was using `Stata` to measure the effects of outsourcing on employment using a panel data and after I ran the regression, I found this in my results:

```
corr(u_i, Xb)  = -0.5617
```

I used fixed effect and time specific dummies to overcome the endogeneity problem. Now I wanted to know whether the result above tells me that I still have endogeneity in my Model?

Answer (score 2):

This number is the empirical correlation between the fixed effect estimate u_i and and expected employment from knowing the time-varying characteristics like outsourcing. This tells you at least three things:

1. The fact that this is large and negative tells you that if you leave the FE out from your model, you are likely to have omitted variable bias in a particular direction because of endogeneity.
2. It also tells you that you probably should not fit a random effects model. You can also formalize this by conducting a Hausman test, which will be more rigorous.
3. It indicates that places that are expected to have high employment also seem to have large negative FEs, which could be given an interesting economic interpretation.

Using the FE effects estimator will take of the time-invariant endogeneity because the FE will be differenced out by the demeaning transformation. If it is removed, it cannot be correlated with the (transformed) error term, creating endogeneity. You might still have time-varying heterogeneity that will mess your estimates up, but this correlation does not really help you figure this out.

Comment: The hausman test told me to use FE, but then when I include industry dummies, hausman tells me to use RE. I think this happened because of collinearity in those industry dummies after using FE approach (here the value is smaller: corr(u_i, Xb)= 0.0912). So is it a bad idea to switch to a RE approach after including industry dummies?

Comment: @Kolo69 I am not sure how those dummies are identified with `xtreg, fe` since firms don't change industries, so I am hesitant to give advice here when I don't really understand the data. I would suggest that you ask another question where you give more details about your panel structure and show the output of FE, RE, and the Hausman test. The econ SE beta site might also be a good fit for this.

Comment: I have ids for firms in my data and each of them belong to a specific manufacture subsector. So I guess I have a combination of a firm and industry Level data. At the begining I type "xtset id year" and then I run my Regression, which looks like this:  xtreg  ln_emp i.year  sic03_3 tov tae areme fixc_00 outnarrow_aaa2, fe vce(robust). Then I include for my industry variable also *sic03_3* a dummy with the i.  . xtreg  ln_emp i.year  i.sic03_3 tov tae areme fixc_00 outnarrow_aaa2, fe vce(robust). And here many subsectors are omitted due to collinearity and hausman tells me to use RE.

Comment: @Kolo69 That makes it sound like it is better to stick with the FE approach then.

Comment: OK then I will stick to FE and explain that RE can not be used, as its assumptions are not fullfilled. Thanks

Comment: @Kolo69 Please select this as the answer if it accomplished that.

Comment: Notice that if some dummies are omitted from a categorical group, your are implicitly assuming that they belong to the same category than the base group! For example, if your base group is agriculture, and due to low observations, public sector is omitted, you are assuming agriculture and public sector have **the same effect** on employment. Whenever you encounter collinearity problems, **do not just let Stata omit variables**. Combine them yourself based on your knowledge. The final model should not omit anything! I'm not sure whetehr this will salvage your problem but still.

Comment: Why the heck is this in the front page if it is ridiculously old? Just realize...